# How Dropbox sync works

Tags: algorithm, cloud, fuse

I'm asking this question out of curiosity.

When I copy 1 GB  file into Dropbox server, it automatically updates in my local machine Dropbox folder but in file property it shows **size** as 1 GB and **size on disk** as 0, once I double click on the file it starts downloading and **size on disk** will set as 1 GB.

How are they handling the file metadata. are they setting file property or showing thumbnail which looks like a file or are they following their own filesystem like `FUSE`.I would like to know more about it. what is the logic behind this ?

Comment: This probably answers your question: ["size on disk" is zero for non-zero file in windows 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22994017)

Comment: @Dukeling Thank you, it clarifies my doubt and last thing is can we modify file size by programmatically like how we modify file LMD using 'File.SetLastWriteTime(path, new DateTime(1985, 4, 3));'